# MPI reduction on user defined communicator

Tags: fortran, mpi, openmpi

Currently I am working on an MPI code in Fortran. After using `mpi_cart_create` then `mpi_group_excl` to create a new group with half of the nodes in it, I am trying to perform a reduction using this communicator but I am obviously doing something wrong.

With the code

```
call MPI_cart_create(MPI_comm_world, 2, dims, (/.false.,.false./), reorder, comm_cart, ierr)
if (ierr/=0) stop 'Error with MPI_cart_create'

call MPI_group_excl(group_world, dims(2), excl_a, division_comm_a, ierr)
if (ierr/=0) stop 'Error with MPI_group_excl - division_comm_a'

call MPI_group_excl(group_world, dims(2), excl_b, division_comm_b, ierr)
if (ierr/=0) stop 'Error with MPI_group_excl - division_comm_b'

if (div_a_rank .gt. 0) then
    call MPI_reduce(division_a(1), division_a(1), L_outer_y, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_SUM, &
    & 0, division_comm_a, ierr)
    if (ierr/=0) stop 'Error with MPI_reduce on division_comm_a'
end if
```

the error I am getting is :

```
*** An error occurred in MPI_Reduce
*** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
*** MPI_ERR_ARG: invalid argument of some other kind
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL: your MPI job will now abort
```

Following an answer I have used `MPI_comm_create_group`, however I am still getting

```
*** An error occurred in MPI_Reduce
*** reported by process [140046521663489,140045998620672]
*** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
*** MPI_ERR_ARG: invalid argument of some other kind
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
***    and potentially your MPI job)
```

Comment: I've re-formatted the new error, but I also agree with Wesley Bland that it may be better if you take that out and ask a new question (showing the new code).  I've also changed a bit of the wording: if you're not happy with what I've written please do roll-back.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're mixing groups and communicators. In MPI, a group is just a logical collection of processes. It can't be used to communicate.

If you want to create a new communicator from your new group, you should use the function `MPI_COMM_CREATE_GROUP`. You can pass your new group into that function to create a new communicator that you can use for your reduction.

Comment: I have created the new communicator but I am still getting errors with MPI reduce

Comment: Then you probably have a different problem. You should post that as a separate question.